# read variables from wp-config.php

Tags: bash, shell, variables, scripting

I'm busy writing a basic migration scripts for some WP sites, and i'm trying to automate creating mysql database and user credentials from reading the wp-config file

how can i read the following variables from the wp-config file so that i effectively end up with 3 variables within a bash script:

```
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'somedbname');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'someusername');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'somerandompassword');
```

eg my output should effectively give me:

```
WPDBNAME=somedbname
WPDBUSER=somedbuser
WPDBPASS=somerandompassword
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try this:

```
WPDBNAME=`cat wp-config.php | grep DB_NAME | cut -d \' -f 4`
WPDBUSER=`cat wp-config.php | grep DB_USER | cut -d \' -f 4`
WPDBPASS=`cat wp-config.php | grep DB_PASSWORD | cut -d \' -f 4`
```

Comment: had to make sure that filename is correct but this does exactly what i need it to do, thanks

Comment: Just a hint on cat: There's no need to combine cat and grep. You can just `grep DB_NAME wp-config-php`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use wp-config details to connect to mysql you can use;

```
mysql -u `cat wp-config.php | grep DB_USER | cut -d \' -f 4` -p`cat wp-config.php | grep DB_PASSWORD | cut -d \' -f 4` -h `cat wp-config.php | grep DB_HOST | cut -d \' -f 4` `cat wp-config.php | grep DB_NAME | cut -d \' -f 4`
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use awk:

```
awk -F"[()']" '/^define/{printf "%s=\"%s\"\n", $3, $5;}' < foo.php
```

This will give you:

```
DB_NAME="somedbname"
DB_USER="someusername"
DB_PASSWORD="somerandompassword"
```

Note, that this solution will work with variables containing spaces.

Comment: while this works perfectly it reveals lots of extra data that i dont need and would need to be amended so as not to have the "

Comment: You can add ` | grep DB_` to the end of that to just get the DB info.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of the universal way to pass php variables to bash without the need to parse:

```
#!/bin/bash

source <(php -r 'require("wp-config.php"); echo("DB_NAME=".DB_NAME."; DB_USER=".DB_USER."; DB_PASSWORD=".DB_PASSWORD); ')
mysqldump --user $DB_USER --password="$DB_PASSWORD" $DB_NAME | gzip > $DB_NAME-$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).sql.gz
```

#### Algorithm explanation in a few words:

1. run your php
2. print variables as var=value
3. source output
4. use variables in bash

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -name "wp-config.php" -print0 | xargs -0 -r grep -e "DB_NAME" -e "DB_USER" -e "DB_PASSWORD"
```

Comment: this reveals the data but doesnt actually answer the question Femi's anwser above does

Comment: Great this is what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to dump the MySQL database, you can also use `wp-cli db export` function:

```
wp db export --path=PATHTOYOURWP
```

Comment: If you use wp-cli, which I highly recommend because it lets you to script many tasks, specially if you have several wordpress sites. I recommend the wp-cli config get command:
<br>  

`wp-cli config get DB_NAME | DB_USER | DB_PASSWORD | WP_HOME | WP_SITEURL`